# Converting 3d model from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made parachute in blender, and then I copy that file to Assets/Prefabs.
I can't use it in my game, icon of that file is not how it should be, here is image what I have got.
Any kind of help will be welcome.

Sorry if I made mistake in English

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGcVr.jpg

Comment: I think you have to export as something!  Maybe FBX ?  https://all3dp.com/2/blender-to-unity-how-to-import-blender-models-in-unity/

Comment: Just like ‘Fattie’ said, you should import as an fbx. Check another link out: [fbx exporting](https://online.ts2009.com/mediaWiki/index.php/HowTo/Export_from_Blender_using_FBX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to keep it as blender file u should put it directly in the project folder and not drag it into Unity. But be aware that, it's better to use FBX, especially if u have large files.

Answer (score 0):

In blender go to
file>export>FBX
Choose a name and location for your file in the window that pops up and hit "Export FBX" This will produce a file unity can read.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlOZM.png